# Is there a way to restore a neo4j 3.5 database without a backup from a persistent volume?

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j

I had a neo4j 3.5 enterprise edition running in a kubernetes cluster.
The cluster was deleted by error with any chance to make a recent neo4j database backup.
The only related things remaining to the old database are three Persistent Disk in the Google Cloud Compute Engine.

Is it possible to recover o restore the data stored in them? How?

The disk detail:

```
{"kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name":"pvc-fd4fe6eb-2c24-11ea-bd38-42010a8e0228",
"kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name":"datadir-neo4j-neo4j-core-2",
"kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace":"default"}
```

The *Secret* storing the old password is lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to first identify which disk hold the `<neo4j-home>/data` directory. Then create a snapshot of this disk (to be safe). Finally, you start a new neo4j pod by create a [volume from the snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/volume-snapshots) and mount to `<neo4j-home>/data`.